# Why the list of objects is not set as list rather than have repeated key for each value while working with proto files in java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, rpc, grpc-java

I have a below proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.anusoft";

message Request {
    repeated string subjects = 1;
}
```

When I compile it and tries to construct its objects as below:

```
Request request1 = Request.newBuilder()
            .setSubjects(0, "Maths")
            .setSubjects(1, "Science")
            .build();
```

I get below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:448)
    at com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList.set(LazyStringArrayList.java:140)
    at com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList.set(LazyStringArrayList.java:61)
    at com.anusoft.Request$Builder.setSubjects(Request.java:468)
    at com.anusoft.grpc.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

When I try to construct object as below:

```
Request request2 = Request.newBuilder()
            .addAllSubjects(Arrays.asList("Maths", "Science"))
            .build();
```

I get response as below when print the object :

```
subjects: "Maths"
subjects: "Science"
```

But I expect it to be like :

```
subjects: ["Maths", "Science"]
```

This is a kind of dummy example I have presented. Similar to this I have one request object proto file and I have compiled it to java and when I tried constructing a Request object in order to request server to send response. The request is being created this way and the request is not getting processed due to malformed request object.

The server is written in .net and they provided us the proto files so as we can convert them into java files and call their method to get response. I have compiled them and using the methods generated to set the fields in request object but when it comes to the repeated fields. They getting formed this way and I am not able to get the response.

Please let me know if anything seems incomplete or vague.

Any helps would be appreciated ! :)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want the object as : subjects: ["Maths", "Science"]

Comment: How are you printing the object? Why do you care exactly what representation `toString` uses?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a misunderstanding.

> I get response as below when print the object :
>
> ```
> subjects: "Maths"
> subjects: "Science"
> ```
>
> But I expect it to be like :
>
> ```
> subjects: ["Maths", "Science"]
> ```

Those two representations mean the same thing in text protobuf. A list is a "repeated field" which means that field is present multiple times. The `[]` syntax is a convenience in text proto. On-the-wire and API there is no difference between those two representations.

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf has 3 different representations for messages:

- The Protobuf binary format: used for communicating between between Protobuf nodes
- A JSON format: used to communicate between a Protobuf node and a web node
- An old text format: used for printing/debugging

The text format you are referencing is basically a debug string and does not matter. You should be writing the binary format instead.

That being said, the binary format actually also writes repeated fields in a [key:value][key:value][key:value] fashion. Only repeated primitives with [packed=true] are written as a single contiguous block entry, e.g., [key,length,]. Those details are handled by Protobuf though and do not need to be worried about.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try below instead of adding subjects as a list

```
 Request request = Request.newBuilder()
        .addSubject("Maths")
        .addSubject("Science")
        .build();
```

Comment: I have tried but it didn't worked.